# Angular + Spring boot Deployment as a war

Tags: node.js, spring, angular, maven, spring-boot

I have two projects one is Angular Project(Front End Application )  and another one is Spring boot (Rest Api's) .

Now I want to generate a single runnable war/jar file for both these projects  and after running "java -jar" command it should up the Angular module as well as spring boot module

Comment: Build your Angular app via `ng build` and put the resulting `dist` directory under `src/main/resources/static`....Furthermore this can be combined by using frontend-maven-plugin...

Answer (score 0):

On the backend build process, after the frontend module is built, you can copy what's in the frontend build directory into `${project.projectDir}/src/main/resources/static/` so both modules can be packaged into one single jar. Here is an example using Gradle:

```
task moveFrontendToResources(type: Copy) {
    from "../frontend/build/"
    into "${project.projectDir}/src/main/resources/static/"
}

moveFrontendToResources.dependsOn(':frontend:bundle')
processResources.dependsOn(moveFrontendToResources)
```

Comment: what about "npm install" command in angular project  how that command will be executed ...... and without "npm install"  dependencies (node_modules folder ) will not be downloaded and "angular 4/5" module will not work

Comment: You should define these tasks to be managed with your build tool, then declare dependencies upon them. I don't really know how to do it using Maven but it should be a way to do that. You can take a look on [shop-finder](https://github.com/DevAnouar/shop-finder), I have splited the project into two modules (backend & frontend) and defined a build file on each one. The one in the frontend defines tasks for bundling etc, and the latter defines the entire build process. Take the principles from there and implement it with Maven assuming you are using it!

Comment: You should check [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) too!